# using exp for exponential form (C++, 1.#INF)

Tags: c++

Is there any way  to use exponential form in exp function of c++?

I guess 1.00e+006 is same to 10^6.

However if i use e for exp function, it gives wrong result 1.#INF as shown below.

```
cout << exp(1.00e+006) << endl; // result : 1.#INF
cout << exp(10^6) << endl; // result : 162755
```

Actually, in my code, i use a "double A" variable, and in some reason, it has exponential form (like e+006). And I have to change A to  exp(A). What's the problem?

Comment: By the way `^` is XOR so `10^6` is 12, not a million.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise-XOR operator.  It does not perform exponentiation.  And _e_ to the power 1 million is a number too large to fit in a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

- `exp(1e6)` is e<sup>10<sup>6</sup></sup>.
- `10^6` is 10 XOR 6
- `1e6` is 1000000

Answer (score 1):

The exp() function is not necessary to interpret floating point literals in C++, and in fact it does something else entirely. It computes e to the x.

e to the millionth is such a large number, it's entirety unsurprising that it overflows a double, giving you the 1.#INF result.

The ^ operator doesn't do exponentiation. It does bitwise xor.

- 10 is 1010 in binary
- 6 is 0110 in binary
- The result of the xor is 1100 in binary, which is 12. And e to the 12th is close to 162755.